# Would an online employment directory for graduates of Christian Colleges be discriminatory?

Tags: employment, discrimination, religion, religious-law

I recently read [an article](http://www.secularleft.us/archives/2013/08/yes-attempt-to-recruit-christian-workers-violates-state-and-federal-law.html) describing an employer who was trying to recruit Christian workers because he felt they were more honest. The article claims this behavior is breaking Federal Anti-discrimination Laws.

**My question:** Would the following job marketplace break these laws:

- Christian college grads setup a profile
- Employers sign up with positions they're looking to fill
- Employers get sent a list of grads that could be a fit for the position

My thought is that the marketplace itself would not break these laws. The employers would be responsible to not use this as the sole source of new hires.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "marketplace"? Do you mean something like an employment agency or job-information posting service, which is utterly independent of employers?

Comment: Sounds like a dating site :)

Comment: @user6726 my marketplace i mean a place where employers can sign up and note their interest (positions) and graduates from Christian colleges can sign up with their resume and we match them together, like a dating site (BlueDogRanch) - expect only the employers would receive lists of potential matches which they can contact as they see fit

Answer (score 1):

College graduates are not a protected class, so discriminating based on that is ok. But the sentiment of referring Christians to employers is against the Civil Rights Act of 1964. http://www.eeoc.gov/employers/coverage_employment_agencies.cfm So yes an employment agency for certain college grads is ok but discriminating based on religion in that agency in any respect is illegal.

This answer only applies to federal law. State and municipal law might apply.

Comment: This would be for graduates from christian colleges in our system (not necessarily Christians). Does that change anything?

Comment: As far as I know the Civil Rights Act of 1964 only applies to discrimination directly based on a protected class, any unprotected class, regardless of demographics doesn't apply.